# Single table inheritance and has_many in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, single-table-inheritance

I'm making a simple financial app for funzies. I modeled credits and debits using single table inheritance, where both inherit from transactions. However, each transaction belongs to a user:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Debit < Transaction
end

class Credit < Transaction
end
```

I could create separate controllers for credits and debits and do something like this:

```
@debit = current_user.debits.build(params[:debit])
...
@credit = current_user.credits.build(params[:credit])
...
```

But user does not have the methods debits or credits, only transactions. Alternatively, I could define a single transactions controller:

```
@transaction = current_user.transactions.build(params[:transactions])
```

But then the type is null, and how should I set that if it's protected from mass assignment? It's a bit of pickle either way. Except that pickles taste good.

Comment: Why don't you create the specific associations at user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the type of the transaction in your second example by doing:

```
@transaction = current_user.transactions.build(params[:transactions])
@transaction.type = "Debit"
@transaction.save
```

The only problem with this is that the @transaction instance variable will not be of type Debit until it's saved and reloaded into a different variable.

Comment: Thanks! I did a variation of this:

    `@type = params[:transaction].delete(:type)
    @transaction = current_user.transactions.build(params[:transaction])
    @transaction.type = @type`

Type came in from a hidden field in the view. Couldn't keep it in params because of mass assignment.